# Lua script to execute commands after pressing a few keys

Tags: lua, logitech, logitech-gaming-software

Today I bought a logitek g502x mouse
started writing scripts (I had never written them before)
I looked in different places and saw an interesting option

The script that i make, does not return errors, but for some reason it does not do anything.
What have I done wrong?

```
EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true);
function OnEvent(event, arg)
    if IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then
        repeat
        if IsModifierPressed ("shift") then
            repeat
                    if IsModifierPressed ("w") then
                    ---
                        PressAndReleaseKey("LCTRL") 
                        Sleep(10) 

                        MoveMouseTo(33000, 55000)
                        Sleep(50) 

                        PressMouseButton(1) 
                        Sleep(130) 

                        ReleaseMouseButton(1) 
                        Sleep(10) 

                        PressAndReleaseKey("LCTRL") 
                        Sleep(10)
                    ---
                    end
                   until not IsModifierPressed ("shift")
               end       
        until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
     end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is working as intended, the reason it does not have the desired outcome is because "w" is not a valid parameter for the method `IsModifierPressed()` which (as the name implies) checks modifier keys not normal keys, thus it returns false for "w". The api reference is [here](https://douile.com/logitech-toggle-keys/APIDocs.pdf) and lists all valid modifiers for your convenience on page 17.